# When I ssh just using the IP address, it port forwards directly to a specific computer

Tags: networking, ssh, router, port-forwarding

well, I have 5 computers and today, I set up ssh. I used port forwarding to lead to my 192.168.1.10 xbuntu. I have 4 other computers on the network

However if I were to just ssh to my public IP that was provided from my ISP, lets say ip 98.222.222.38, it goes directly to my 192.168.1.10. How does it know to go directly there? I do not understand since I have 5 computers on 98.222.222.38, how does it know to go to 192.168.1.10 instead of lets say 192.168.1.3?

Comment: That's exactly what port forwarding does. It bridges one port in your router to a port from a specific IP in your subnet.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting directly to an IP address with SSH will attempt a connection on port 22.  Your router has you behind Network Address Translation (NAT) allowing you to use several computers behind a single public IP address.  Your router must have port forwarding rule to forward connections to port 22 on your WAN IP to port 22 on 192.168.1.10.

You'd have to have a separate rule forwarding a different WAN port to 192.168.1.3 port 22 in order to reach ssh on your other interior computer.

This explains how you're connecting to the .10 host when you attempt to connect to your public IP address.

However, from your clarification in the comments beneath this question: ssh assumes the same username on the remote system as on the local host if no username is provided.  Thus, if you use `ssh 98.222.222.38` instead of `ssh will86@98.222.222.38` and can successfully connect, your username on your client machine must be "will86".

Here's the entire process, in effect (particulars of how the network stack work on your router may not be accurately reflected):
when you simply run `ssh 98.222.222.38`:

- Your client machine sends a TCP SYN packet to IP 98.222.222.38, port 22
- Your router receives the packet, routes the packet to 98.222.222.38
- Your router receives the packet on the WAN adapter at 98.222.222.38 port 22
- Your router inspects its NAT port forwarding rules to identify how to route the incoming packet.  In most situations, it'll drop the packet here but your router must have a forwarding rule for port 22 to IP 192.168.1.10 present
- Your router sends the packet to 192.168.1.10, port 22
- 192.168.1.10 receives the packet and responds, continuing through the TCP connection handshake to establish a connection
- Somewhere in the ssh application protocol (which is going to occur via the established TCP connection) a username is required.  As one is not provided on the command line, the client uses the username of the logged in user who launched the ssh client application.  If you specified `ssh vt_antik@98.222.222.38`, it would instead attempt to use vt_antik for the username.

Comment: I dont think you understand the question.

Comment: ok i think people are misunderstanding the question. If I just type ssh 98.222.222.5 on the command prompt, which is my public IP that my ISP provides me, how does it know to go to 192.168.1.10 if 5 other computers are connected to that same 98.222.222.5 IP? Usually you type in willc86@98.222.222.5 and it knows but all i am typing in is ssh 98.222.222.5

Answer (score 0):

A computer can only allow one application to listen to a specific port at any time. In this case, ssh is on port 22, so sshd is the one which receives connections.

You can think of a router as a surrogate computer for others on the network. In this case, it would be a computer instead of an application listening on a specific port. There's only one 'port 22' on the router, so it can only be forwarded to one computer. If there were no port forward rules, the router itself would accept the connection (and some routers do have ssh access).

You can, however, pick a different port on the router, and forward to another computer's port 22 so that you can access them. For standards' sake, use a port number >1024, because everything <1024 is reserved for other services (e.g. 20-21 is for FTP, 23 is telnet). So, for example, 98.222.222.38:22100 can get port forwarded to 192.168.1.3:22